# PHP Fatal error: Function name must be a string in Error

Tags: php, email, logging

i have this error in my error log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Function name must be a string in /home2/x7w7i0o6/public_html/admin/mail.php on line 41
```

This is the code from line 41:

```
if ($input->p['receiverlist'] == "single") {
    $userid = getuserid($input->pc['username']);

    if ($userid == 0) {
        $serveranswer(0, "Username <strong>" . $input->pc['username'] . "</strong> was not found");
    }
```

What is issue for that because mailer dont works. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put `$` in front of function names (unless you want a [variable function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)).

```
$serveranswer(0, "Username <strong>" . $input->pc['username'] . "</strong> was not found");
```

Should be:

```
serveranswer(0, "Username <strong>" . $input->pc['username'] . "</strong> was not found");
```